# How do I uninstall TeamViewer in Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, teamviewer

How can I uninstall TeamViewer in Vista:

- Locally?
- Remotely?

I know I may not be able to completely uninstall it remotely, or may not get a quick answer on that. However knowing enough on how to uninstall it that I could in theory do it locally would be an improvement on my current situation. I could even get the uninstallation started remotely.

I'm familiar with how to uninstall it in Windows XP but not in Vista.

- I can't find the uninstallation file.
- I don't see it listed in Vista's Control Panel nor a link in the Start Menu

I've found this directory 'C:\Users\halinfamily\AppData\Local\Temp\TeamViewer\Version5' containing the following files:

```
install.exe  
install64.exe  
TeamViewer.exe  
TeamViewer_.exe  
TeamViewer_Desktop.exe  
TeamViewer_Service.exe
```

The following files are found on XP in 'C:\Program Files\TeamViewer\Version5':

```
install.exe
install64.exe
TeamViewer.exe
TeamViewer_Desktop.exe
TeamViewer_Service.exe
uninstall.exe
```

I don't have a local Vista machine to experiment on, but am connected to one remotely, and would like to uninstall it or at least start uninstalling it before disconnecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Team Viewer installer has two operations modes:

- If you use *Install* it will install the program to Program Files (by default), create Start Menu icons and put an uninstaller in the programs section of the Control Panel.
- If you select *Start*, it will extract the required files to the temp directory and will launch the program from there. It won't install anything in the sense that it doesn't put the program in Program Files, don't modify the system configuration (i.e., it doesn't install the TeamViewer service) and doesn't store program settings (by default, I think that you can save some options from the temporal install for future sessions).

It seems that in the Vista machine *Start* was chosen, and what you are seeing is the leftovers of the temporal installation (you can just delete that files).

Comment: I am connected remotely at the moment. How do I stop the server? (i'm guessing it won't start up on restart? that right?..)

Comment: Looks like when you disconnect by closing the window of the machine local to you,or click the red x within the remote window, it still waits at the remote end. and one can reconnect. One can close the teamviewer connect/wait window that is open on the local machine, and it will then disconnect and not wait, so not allow a further connection, but it asks about free registration.. so it's not a clean thing!

Comment: The temporarily install doesn't starts up automatically on restart, unless you use the reconnect after restart option.

Comment: The messy registration question is enough to confuse a clueless user though. And I like to leave someone like that with a nice clear screen.

Comment: I agree that the registration question can be confusing for newbies,  but it's the price you pay for using the program for free. Purchased edition won't have that message.